# GWT: How to set pie chart title center

Tags: charts, alignment

I can't see any options to make chart title center. I'm try to using setHorizontalAlignment (HasHorizontalAlignment) also not effected. Any idea please.

```
private PieChart.PieOptions createPassFailOptions() {
    PieChart.PieOptions options = PieChart.createPieOptions();
    options.setWidth(500);
    options.setHeight(340);
    options.set3D(true);
    options.setFontSize(15);
    options.setBackgroundColor("F0F8FF");
    options.setTitle("Total Passed & Failed");
    options.setColors("lightgreen","lightcoral","yellow");      
    TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle.create();
    textStyle.setColor("black");
    options.setPieSliceTextStyle(textStyle);        
    return options;
  }
        ////////  Draw pie chart
        Runnable onLoadCallback1 = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                PieChart pie = new PieChart(createPassFailTable(), createPassFailOptions());
                pie.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(pie));
                piePassFailPanel.add(pie);
              }
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
PieChart.PieOptions options = ....
Options legend = Options.create();
Options.set("alignment","center");
options.set("legend",legend);
```

Comment: Hi, this answer is to make legend center, but I don't want legend to be center. I want to make Title Chart to be center. "Total Passed & Failed"

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. According to the documentation you can only set the font-style of the title. I would set the title of the `PieChart` to null (disable it) and just add a custom title above the `PieChart` using a `HTMLPanel`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm put the chart into table, disable the chart title and customize chart title as text inside the table. Thanks for your help bro.